# jest module executed even when mocked

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs

I stumble upon the fact that jest still executes module after mocking it. Which have side effects in my case (echarts + zrender).

crashingModule.js:

```
throw 'Module is executed';

foo = () => {
  return 'boom';
}

module.exports = foo;
```

crashingModule.test.js:

```
const foo = require('./crashingModule');
jest.mock('./crashingModule');
```

Result:

> ● Test suite failed to run
>
> ```
> Error
>
>   Module is executed
> ```

That is because Jest internally [run module](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/949701376f1af75befd1a759aff5ac8080fb33af/packages/jest-runtime/src/index.js#L611) even after mocking it.

Is it possible to somehow skip execution of module mocked by jest.mock()?

**Current workaround:**

I came up with a wrapper:

```
const echarts = require('echarts');
const zrenderUtil = require('zrender/lib/core/util');

module.exports = {
  echarts: echarts,
  zrenderUtil: zrenderUtil
}
```

Which is then imported in both our module and test of that module. That way echarts is not executed when wrapper is mocked by Jest. Only wrapper module is run, which have no side effects.

Comment: Well your are importing your module, it will execute your JavaScript anyway, nothing to do with jest at `const foo = require('./crashingModule');`

Comment: jest hijacks module import and mocks it before execution. I can see it in action when I am importing & mocking echarts + zrender. In that case echarts crashing because it execute function from zrender. Which is jest.fn() returning `undefined`.

Comment: I guess this is duplicate of [this Q](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55632256/5739006).

Comment: @WerWet Questions does not look like exact duplication, but answer provides another nice workaround of a problem, thank you.