# Jest: Find out if current module is mocked during runtime

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs

Is there a way i can find out during runtime if a module is mocked via jest?

Since mocked modules get required normally and therefore the code gets executed (as seen here: [jest module executed even when mocked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51609510/jest-module-executed-even-when-mocked=)

We need this because we have checks on top of each file to fail early when a mandatory environment variable is not set, which causes our tests to fail even if the module is mocked.

```
if (!process.env.SOME_ENV) {
  throw new Error(`Mandatory environment variable 'SOME_ENV' not set`)
}
```

We are looking for something like this:

```
if (!process.env.SOME_ENV && utils.isNotMocked(this)) {
  throw new Error(`Mandatory environment variable 'SOME_ENV' not set`)
}
```

where `utils.isNotMocked(this)` is the magic function which checks if the module is currently mocked.

Comment: The last thing you want is for your code under test to *know* it's under test, have you tried setting `process.env.SOME_ENV` *before* importing the modules?

Comment: Of course that would work but we are using a lot of environment variables like this and the whole point of mocking is that we don't wanna deal with the inner workings of the mocked module. It would take some extra unnecessary effort to set all the environment variables to a dummy value. Regarding "The last thing you want is for your code under test to know it's under test" i agree with you but  also i don't want that a mocked module gets executed. IMHO this is a design flaw from jest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @jonrsharpe mentioned, it is typically not desirable that software can distinguish whether it is under test or not.  This means, you will probably not find the feature you are hoping for in any mocking framework.  Moreover, there may be more fundamental problems to provide such a feature, because you might have mixed test scenarios where for some test cases an object of the mocked class is used, and for other test cases an object of the original class is used.

Since you are using the early exit mechanism as a general pattern in your code, as you describe: What about creating a library function for this check - which then again can be doubled during testing such that in that case the function does not throw?